# Update a nuget package for all projects from a private source

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I need to update a package `Package01`, which lives in a **private source**, for multiple projects in a solution from version 1.0.1 to newest version 1.1.0. If doing this update from Package Manager UI, this step needs to be repeated many times.

Is it possible to do just in one step? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a package for all projects in a solution from the Package Manager UI or from the Package Manager Console.

Using the Manage Packages dialog right click the solution and select Manage Packages for the solution. Then update the package. You will be able to update it for multiple projects in one step.

You can also do a similar thing from the Package Manager Console. The command below will update jquery to the latest version for all projects in the solution.

```
Update-Package jquery
```

There is more documentation on the [Update-Command](http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html) on the NuGet web site.

Comment: The command doesn't work with message "no updates available...". The PM UI works for great, I was chosen for project level :). Thanks

Comment: With the Package Manager Console not finding any updates my only guess is that your private source was not selected in the drop down list.

Comment: I found on the link an option -Source and tested it OK ;)